# How can i pass the selected value that is selected in a dropdown of a view to an other dropdown of another view? The options of dropdown come from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, dropdown, selectedvalue

This is my first view named ReplacementForm with the dropdown dimensions that I want to pass his selected value to another dropdown of another view named IndexAdmin.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ReplacementForm";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml";

<div class="container-contact100-form-btn">

<div class="wrap-contact100">
    <h2>Replacement Form</h2>

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
            <label class="label-input100">Replacement Date</label>
            <br />
            <label class="label-input100 " id="dngr" style="color:red">Please chose replacement date</label>
            <input class="input100" type="date" id="dt" required />
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
            <label class="label-input100">Bag Dimensions</label>
            <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="dimensions"> </select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
            <label class="label-input100">Bag Material</label>
            <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="Bag_Type"> </select>
            @Html.ActionLink("Other", "Create", "Bag", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary bt10" })
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
            <label class="label-input100">Supplier</label>
            <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="supplier"> </select>
            @Html.ActionLink("Other", "Create", "Supplier", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary bt10" })
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
            <label class="label-input100">Replacement Reason</label>
            <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="Reason"></select>
            @Html.ActionLink("Other", "Create", "Replacement_Reason", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary bt10" })
        </div>
        <div class="container-contact100-form-btn bb">
            <div class="wrap-contact100-form-btn">
                <div class="contact100-form-bgbtn"></div>

                @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "IndexAdmin", "FilterGraphic", new { @Filter_Code = Session["Filter"], @dd2 = Session["Sector"] }, new { @class = "contact100-form-btn", id = "but" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you can see my destination view where i want to pass the dropdown value and make this value selected on this view.

```
            <h1>
                Replace bags
            </h1>
            <form action="">


                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
                        <label class="label-input100">Replacement Date</label>
                        <br />
                        <label class="label-input100 " id="dngr" style="color:red">Please chose replacement date</label>
                        <input class="input100" type="date" id="dt" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
                        <label class="label-input100">Bag Dimensions</label>
                        <h3>@ViewBag.dimensions</h3>
                        <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="dimensions">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
                        <label class="label-input100">Bag Material</label>
                        <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="Bag_Type"> </select>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Other", "Create", "Bag", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary bt10" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
                        <label class="label-input100">Supplier</label>
                        <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="supplier"> </select>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Other", "Create", "Supplier", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary bt10" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input101 validate-input">
                        <label class="label-input100">Replacement Reason</label>
                        <select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="Reason"></select>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Other", "Create", "Replacement_Reason", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary bt10" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-contact100-form-btn bb">
                        <div class="wrap-contact100-form-btn">
                            <div class="contact100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="contact100-form-btn" id="sub" type="submit">
                                <span>
                                    Submit
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-contact100-form-btn bb">
                        <div class="wrap-contact100-form-btn">
                            <div class="contact100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Valve Maintenance", "Create", "ValvesMaintenance", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "contact100-form-btn" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
```

The options of the select list(dropdown) come from database. How can I pass the value of my dropdown to the value of the other dropdown in the other view? Both views belong to the same controller.

Here are my controller actions of source and destination views.

```
public ActionResult ReplacementForm(string Filter_Code, int dd2)
    {
        Session["Filter"] = Filter_Code;
        Session["Sector"] = dd2;
        var data = db.Filters.SqlQuery("select * from Filters where Filter_Code=@p0", Filter_Code).ToList();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            ViewBag.allSec = item.No_Of_Sectors;


        }
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Super")]
    public ActionResult IndexAdmin(string Filter_Code, int dd2,string dimensions)
    {
        string cDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
        
        ViewBag.dimensions=dimensions;
        ViewBag.sec = dd2;
        ViewBag.fil = Filter_Code;
        Session["sec"] = dd2;
        Session["fil"] = Filter_Code;
        var data = db.Filters.SqlQuery("select * from Filters where Filter_Code=@p0", Filter_Code).ToList();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            ViewBag.allSec = item.No_Of_Sectors;
            int[,] x = new int[item.Bags_Per_Valve + 1, item.Sector_No_Valves + 1];

            for (int i = 1; i <= item.Bags_Per_Valve; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= item.Sector_No_Valves; j++)
                {

                    var data1 = db.Bag_Replacement.SqlQuery("select * from Bag_Replacement where Filter_Code=@p0 AND Sector_No=@p1 AND Bag_No=@p2  AND Valve_no=@p3 ", Filter_Code, dd2, i, j).ToList();
                    foreach (var item2 in data1)
                    {
                        if (item2.Create_Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy") == DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy"))
                        {
                            x[i, j] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    data1.Clear();
                }
            }
            ViewBag.x = x;

        }

        return View(data);
    }
```